# RN - React Navigation type for map of screens

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a navigator with the type definitions:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  User: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  ...
  ...
  Profile: undefined;
  ProfileDetails: undefined;
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

Now, all is good for individual screens but one part of the navigator is a map of screens coming from a different file:

```
 {UserScreens.map(s => (
        <Stack.Screen
          key={s.name}
          name={s.name} // <= the name key is highlighted in red with the error below
          component={s.component}
          options={s.options}
        />
      ))}
```

The TS error I get is:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof
> RootStackParamList'.  types.d.ts(358, 5): The expected type comes from
> property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> RouteConfig<RootStackParamList, keyof RootStackParamList,
> StackNavigationState, StackNavigationOptions,
> StackNavigationEventMap>'

The UserScreens is a separate file:

```
const UserScreens = [
  {
    name: 'Profile',
    component: Profile,
    options: {
      ...,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'ProfileDetails',
    component: ProfileDetails,
    options: {
      ...,
    },
  },
  ...
];

export default UserScreens;
```

In RootStackParamList, I have listed all those screen names/keys that are coming from mapping over UserScreens (eg. Profile, ProfileDetails).

Comment: Hey, @Wasteland did you find any solution to do that cause I am currently trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and **not recommended** fix because you will not benefit from typescript type checking is to simply give UserScreens array a type of "any" :)

```
const UserScreens:any = [
  {
  ...
  } 
];
```

the **better suggestion** is to give it a proper type where the "name" property type is "keyof RootStackParamList"

```
type UserScreen = {
    name: keyof RootStackParamList;
    component: ... 
    options: ... 
};

const UserScreens: UserScreen[] = [
  {
   .... 
   ..
   ....

  {
]
```

Comment: Thanks. In the 'better' suggestion, what would be the type for 'component' (an imported screen) and the 'options' object (where key:value pairs are different across different screens?